# Switch Case en C#

Tags: c#

Hola tengo una duda y es que quiero que entre al case cada vez que coincida el fichero según su tipo es decir si al buscar en la carpeta encuentra tipo ASIENTOS que entre al case de "ASIENTOS".
El problema es que no entra nunca al case habiendo archivos dentro.

```
foreach (var fi in di.GetFiles("*.csv"))
        {
            string valor = fi.Name;
            switch (valor)
            {
                case "ASIENTOS":

                    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(fi.FullName)) // pasamos el path del fichero csv
                    {
                        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                        parser.SetDelimiters(";"); // delimitador de csv
                        while (!parser.EndOfData)
                        {
                            //Processing row
                            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();

                            DTO.Cl_LineaAC linea = new DTO.Cl_LineaAC();
                            linea.documento = fields[0].PadLeft(6, '0');
                            
                            if (hashDiccionari.ContainsKey(linea.documento) == false)
                            {
                                List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = new List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC>();
                                lista.Add(linea);
                                hashDiccionari.Add(linea.documento, lista);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                List<DTO.Cl_LineaAC> lista = hashDiccionari[linea.documento];
                                lista.Add(linea);
                            }

                        }// fin


                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: Me resulta curioso que hayas marcado como aceptada una respuesta que te recomienda una funcion de c++ cuando tu codigo es claramente C#. Podrías explicarlo?

Comment: No soy experto en C# pero un consulta rápida a la documentación me informa que fi.Name del objeto FileInfo contiene el nombre completo del fichero, incluyendo la extensión y has buscado aquellos ficheros terminados en .csv, así que si el fichero "ASIENTOS.csv" está en tu directorio NO se va a procesar en un case asociado a "ASIENTOS", el case debería ser "ASIENTOS.csv". Si quieres procesar todos los ficheros que EMPIECEN por "ASIENTOS" deberías usar un if y no un case.

Comment: Para obtener sólo el nombre del archivo y en mayúsculas puedes utilizar `Path.GetFileName(fi.Name).ToUpper()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asegúrate de que dentro del fichero tienes escrita la misma cadena que estás intentando buscar, mayúsculas incluidas, ya que no es lo mismo 'a' que 'A', etc. (cada una tiene un valor ASCII diferente)
Si esto no da resultado, te recomiendo utilizar `strcmp` (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Saludos.